# How you would do this in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a controller named `manageCountriesAction` where I generate a form from the fuction `createCountryForm(Countries $entity)` and I receive the `Request` to `createCountryAction` function.

Now the tricky part that I don't know how figure it out, If the form isn't valid or there's any validation error how I could redirect them to `manageCountriesAction` and finally display them in the template (E.g: this field can't be empty)?

Here's the code

```
<?php

namespace CarsProject\BackendBundle\Controller;

use CarsProject\BackendBundle\Entity\Countries;
use CarsProject\BackendBundle\Form\CountriesType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class AdminPanelController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Locations: manage countries controller
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function manageCountriesAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $countries = $em->getRepository('CarsProjectBackendBundle:Countries')->findAll();

        $newEntity = new Countries();
        $formNewCountry = $this->createCountryForm($newEntity);

        return $this->render('CarsProjectBackendBundle:Backend:manage_countries.html.twig', array(
            'countries_entity' => $countries,
            'form_new_country' => $formNewCountry->createView()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Create action for Countries Entity
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function createCountryAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Countries();
        $form = $this->createCountryForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('cars_project_backend_manage_countries');
        }

        /* *
         * If submitted data or $form isn't valid then redirect the response (form validation errors)
         * to "manageCountriesAction" controller and finally make the validation errors appear
         * in the twig template of "manageCountriesAction" controller.
         **/

    }

    /**
     * Create form for Countries Entity
     *
     * @param Countries $entity
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form
     */
    public function createCountryForm(Countries $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new CountriesType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('cars_project_backend_manage_countries_form_new'),
            'method' => 'POST'
        ));

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Comment: in `createCountryAction` add `else` in if where you check `$form->isValid()` and then redirect to this action either with redirect() or redirectToRoute

Comment: hey @Robert that isn't really working, I'm not getting the form validation errors in the template.

Comment: Did you declare all your validation rules ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Comment: @sdespont sure, I added them. http://codepad.org/5uvztgjv

Comment: If you really need to redirect on error then you will need to save the errors in the session and pull them back out again.  Much easier to just follow the example in the documentation and use a single action method for get and post.

Comment: @Cerad it seems the way to go, thank you for your comment btw.